# About the definition of the spin current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

People have been talking about the spin current for a while. But there is a fundamental problem. Unlike charge, or mass, spin is not conserved.

Let us take the 1d spin-1/2 Heisenberg chain as an example. Suppose we flip a up spin to down spin. This does not generate any current, but the z-value of the spin has changed, I would argue.

So is the concept of spin current really meaningful? The problem is that there is no such equation as

$$ \frac{d \rho}{dt} + \nabla\cdot J = 0.  $$

Comment: Spin is part of the conservation of angular momentum. If the axial current is null ($\bar{\psi} \gamma^5 \psi = 0$), spin is also conserved independently. Otherwise, you use the usual conservation law, something of the form $\partial_c L^{abc} + \partial_c S^{abc} = 0$, with L the angular momentum and S the spin density (Don't have the exact formula in mind)

Comment: I do not understand. But could you confine yourself to the non-relativistic regime?

Comment: Why do you think there is no such thing as a continuity equation for spins?
https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0405312.pdf